# How to import module in Python from a path passed by argument?

Tags: python

I have four projects. Three of them (A, B, C) have custom Python module (which has same name but there are differences in functionality) that fourth project (D) is using.

In project D I need to import that module, but which (from project A, B or C) will be imported depends on provided path. How can I achieve this? I have this (pseudo)code:

```
import mymodule

# code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(--path)

    path = args[0].path
    # now I need to use this variable 'path' to insert it to sys.path so that `import mymodule` will work
    sys.path.insert(0, path)
```

This, of course, won't work because Python interprets code line by line from the beginning of file. So it will throw exception `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Is there some way to achieve this except adding this part of code with `argparser` at the top of file before line `import mymodule'?

Comment: You can put `import mymodule` _after_ setting the `sys.path`.

Comment: Just move the import line down

Comment: You could use `importlib` - see [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) - but it's not really any better than just moving the import statement below the argparse logic (you may as well remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard too, it's not helping anything here)

Comment: You all are very correct, I don't know why didn't I think of just moving `import mymodule` after setting `sys.path` in `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Now I am a bit embarrassed. I guess this is sign to go home, it is Friday and end of workday here, after all. Thank you all once more.